# moving between indexes in a list in python

Tags: python-3.x

In Python, I populate info from a file to a list and then print the first index in the list, now I want to print the next index from the list without multiple my code.

How can I promote the index i'm printing?

```
question = open("questions.txt", "r")

print(question.readlines()[0])

tanswer = open("answers.txt", "r")

correct_answer = float(tanswer.readlines()[0])

uanswer = float(input("Write the answer: "))

if correct_answer==uanswer:
    print("Amazing " + str(correct_answer) + " is the correct answer")
else:
    print("Wrong " + str(uanswer) + " is not correct, Try again please. ")
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you are trying to split the lines.
let's say

```
line = '1000 2000 3000'
line = line.split(' ')
```

then you will get line[0]

Try this I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, i would like to run this function in a loop where every time the function will print the next index (line in a list) will be printed, in this run: print(question.readlines()[0]) it will print index 0, in the next run it will print index 1 and so on until the end of the list

Answer (score 0):

Use zip:

```
with open("questions.txt") as ques, open("answers.txt") as ans:
    for q, a in zip(ques, ans):
        print(q)
        uanswer = input("Write the answer: ")

        if float(a) == float(uanswer):
            print("Amazing " + str(a) + " is the correct answer")
        else:
            print("Wrong " + str(uanswer) + " is not correct, Try again please. ")
```